# How do I find a shared key value from a MySQL table of matched pairs?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two column MySQL table which represents the variations of a product with three different options (size, colour etc.)

```
##############################
#  VariationID  #  OptionID  #
##############################
#            1  #        10  #
#            1  #        20  #
#            1  #        30  #
#            2  #        11  #
#            2  #        20  #
#            2  #        30  #
#            3  #        10  #
#            3  #        22  #
#            3  #        30  #
#            4  #        10  #
#            4  #        20  #
#            4  #        33  #
##############################
```

The table is generated by the PHP framework I'm using (Silverstripe) so I can't easily modify it.

How do I identify which **VariationID** is matched to specific options?

Can I run a MySQL query that returns the VariationID for the variation with the OptionIDs 10,20,30?

If it isn't possible in raw MySQL what's the best approach in PHP?

Comment: Combination of `WHERE OptionID IN(…)`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(…) = 3` … similar questions have been discussed multiple times before, so I suggest you do some research using those keywords.

Comment: @CBroe the typical answer with `IN()`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT()` tend to be worst case for the MySQL optimizer.

Comment: @EugenRieck, I know it’s not the best performance-wise – but what are you gonna do when it’s not looking for 3 options any more, but a dozen or two – write two dozen JOINs? Not sure if that’s better.

Comment: @CBroe if it is a dozen or more, the cost of doing the complete `GROUP BY` to a temporary table, and only then filtering it by `HAVING` is even greater. So while this is counterintuitive, even then the `JOIN` will typically perform much better. The `GROUP BY` is faster, if very low selectivity is achieved, i.e. when few rows are in the base table, but many conditions need to be join-checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL directly, but it is a bit messy:

```
SELECT 
  A.VariationID AS VariationID
FROM
  tablename AS A
  INNER JOIN tablename AS B ON A.VariationID=B.VariationID
  INNER JOIN tablename AS C ON A.VariationID=C.VariationID
WHERE
  A.OptionID=10
  AND B.OptionID=20
  AND C.OptionID=30
```

This will find the `VariationID` of rows, that exist for `OptionID` values of 10, 20 and 30

Comment: Is there a reason you used two joins rather than just `in`?

Comment: The classical `IN()`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT()` tend to perform very badly on MySQL, while the `JOIN` is rather fast, if indices are in place and a sensible selectivity is assumed.

Comment: Perfect - thank you for your comment about this approach vs IN, GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT() - very helpful.